# Was Liberty Island Jean Grey's first mission?

Tags: marvel, x-men-cinematic-universe, x-men-2000

One of the main reasons I got to thinking about this is due to what happens in the gift shop fight. First off, she seems to jump slightly when Cyclops orders her and Storm to back up so he can blast down the massive steel door separating them from Wolverine.

Next, she not only shows herself to be easily intimated by Toad, but also hesitates and appears uncertain what to do, giving Toad an opportunity to slime her and nearly kill her.

Note: While I understand that Sophie Turner's version of Jean Grey did missions in the 80s and 90s, that happened because of the re-written timeline, caused by an event after the first *X-Men* film.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presumably not. In the prequel comic *X-Men Movie Prequel: Rogue*, Jean is seen alongside Storm and Cyclops, in her X-Men outfit, searching for Rogue, who recently discovered her powers. The X-Men fail to reach out to her, she escapes and eventually ends up where she joins Wolverine in the movie.

[image: the X-Men team is introduced]

Thus, Liberty Island was probably not her first mission. The goofiness you mention might be due to her still being uncomfortable with what she saw in Wolverine's mind, the stress of the situation, or a slow directorial move towards her powers becoming unstable because if the Phoenix.

Comment: @Jenayah-Hey, when you get a chance, can we discuss some things in chat?

Comment: @Gothamite24 sure, anytime. I should always be pingable in [The Restaurant at the End of the Universe](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58631/the-restaurant-at-the-end-of-the-universe). See ya